# As they were all qualified, how/why were the Apollo Astronauts chosen for their individual missions?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, astronauts, lunar-landing

Why did some fly multiple Apollo missions, while others flew only once?

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23146/how-did-nasa-choose-who-descended-in-the-lem-during-the-apollo-missions?rq=1 seems pretty closely related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer seems closely related to my original intent of the question.

[How did NASA choose who descended in the LEM during the Apollo missions?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23146/how-did-nasa-choose-who-descended-in-the-lem-during-the-apollo-missions)